# Coingecko api 404 angular get request

Tags: angular, api, get, http-status-code-404, coingecko

I'm trying to pull data from coin gecko api, but I'm getting status 404 error and the body is returning error: "Collection 'v3' not found". The api url I'm using is https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd.

I'm working with Angular and using an https.get request.

This is my service class

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  api: string = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd';

  getCoinData(): Observable<Coin[]> {
    return this.http.get<Coin[]>(this.api, httpOptions);
  }
```

This is my component ts file

```
constructor(private cryptoCoinService : CryptoCoinsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTopCoins();
  }

  getTopCoins() {
    this.cryptoCoinService.getCoinData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.topCoins = data;
      },
      err => console.log(err));
  }
```

It should return

```
{
  "bitcoin": {
    "usd": 17274.17
  }
}
```

Comment: Your URL, display correct JSON response without token.
Click [here](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd)   I am using your URL. Why you need the Token?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I figured it out I forgot I was using InMemoryDataService from earlier when I was testing some stuff, I just had to comment those parts out.